# VirtualBox - Application Error

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I have an Ubuntu 18.0.4 VM running one my of projects. However, the unknown error below, unpredictably pops up. This terminates my VM every time, so I cannot work efficiently.

I tried to do some googling, but none of the solutions I found works for me.

Here is the pop-up error:

[image: pop-up error]

Here are my VM's specifications:

[image: VM's specifications]

Comment: One reason you might be getting this error is if your virtual memory settings are very low.

Comment: @SachinYadav you see the pic 2, my system base memory have 4096MB, around 4GB, not enough ? can you suggest me ?

Comment: Run System File Checker sfc /scannow

Comment: How much **physical memory** does your **host** system have? Can you paste `head -2 /proc/meminfo` output.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli get this error 'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry; I was assuming that your **host** system is also Ubuntu. In Windows, you can go the System Properties to see how much memory your physical system has got.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli where to find System Properties ?

Comment: Host system : The physical system that you run VirtualBox. It seems you are using Windows. How much physical memory does this system have? You can right click on **This PC** and select **Properties**. Look for **Installed Memory (RAM):**

Comment: @FedonKadifeli i have 12 RAM

Comment: @SachinYadav i get this Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

Comment: Use DISM. Open an elevated command prompt and run the following command and hit Enter:

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
This command checks for component store corruption, records the corruption and FIXES the corruption. It may take a while though! Useful if System File Checker is not working

Comment: @SachinYadav Hi, just try your suggestion , it stuck at 100% , I found this youtube https://youtu.be/Od60db_2gp0?t=100 it have message after 100%, but im not